# error while uploading image to server in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I want to upload an image to server i am using following code for it.

```
 pickImageFromGallery(ImageSource source) {
    setState(() {
      imageFile = ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
    });
  }
```

for showing image in imageview

```
FutureBuilder<File>(
        future: imageFile,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<File> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
              snapshot.data != null) {
            image = snapshot.data;
            print('image ${image}');
            return new Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                    width: 140.0,
                    height: 140.0,
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      image: new DecorationImage(
                        image: new FileImage(snapshot.data),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    )),
              ],
            );
          } else if (snapshot.error != null) {
            return const Text(
              'Error Picking Image',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            );
          }
```

After that i call following function on button pressed for send image to server::

```
 upload(image) async {


    // open a bytestream
    var stream =
        new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(image.openRead()));
    // get file length
    var length = await image.length();

    // string to uri
    var uri =
        Uri.parse("myurl");

    // create multipart request
    var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

    // multipart that takes file
    var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('profile', stream, length,
        filename: basename(image.path));

    // add file to multipart
    request.files.add(multipartFile);
    request.fields['first_name'] = first_name;
    request.fields['last_name'] = last_name;
    request.fields['email'] = email;
    request.fields['mobile'] = mobile;
    request.fields['password'] = password;
    request.fields['zipcode'] = zipcode;
    request.fields['dob'] = dob;
    request.fields['state'] = state;
    request.fields['city'] = city;
    request.fields['address'] = address;
    request.fields['qualification'] = qualification;
    request.fields['vehicles'] = inputs_value.toString();
    request.fields['service_id'] = service_id;
    request.fields['rate'] = rate;
    request.fields['experience'] = experience;
    request.fields['quick_pitch'] = quick_pitch;
print('data ${ request.fields.toString()}');
    // send
    var response = await request.send();
    print(response.statusCode);
    response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
      print(value);
    });
  }
```

it gives an error 403 forbidden[image]

my api is perfectly running fine without any error in postman.
i can not getting the issue please help!!

If i call web service without passing image i.e if i call my API simply not using multipart it is working without this error, so problem is in image passing..i didn't get where i m wrong in passing image.

Comment: It is not server error. Network error. You are blocked to that domain.

Comment: I suggest you to make a request from Dart code to a mirroring API to check what's going on. You can also use network tools like Fiddler etc.

Comment: Is it WordPress API ?

Comment: No it is an PHP API

Comment: When using postman, are you providing an authentication header?

Comment: no i am not passing ant headers

Comment: @urvashi any update about it ?